# Google Looker Studio - Google Data Studio | Bad performance using table_suffix filter in BigQuery data source

Tags: google-bigquery, reporting, looker-studio

### CONTEXT

Hi,
in bigquery, I have a table that is partitioned by an integer that can be from 0 to 999.
Every time I use this data source in Looker Studio for reporting, I filter this column using a parameter to get the right partition; after that, another filter is used on the date column.
The queries are fast but very expensive.

### GOAL

To reduce cost, I divided the table into 1000 wildcard tables in my big query project and use the date as a partition for all of them.

So,

- before: I have *my_project.big_table* partition by id;
- now: I have *my_project.table_* partition by date and I can use the **table_suffix** to get the right table

In the Looker Studio, I changed the custom query for the data source from:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `my_project.big_table` AS a
WHERE a.date BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) AND PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
      AND a.id = @id1     
      AND a.user_email =    @DS_USER_EMAIL
```

to :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `my_project.table_*` AS a
WHERE a.date BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) AND PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
      AND a._TABLE_SUFFIX = @id1      
      AND a.user_email =    @DS_USER_EMAIL
```

### ISSUE DESCRIPTION

the change above caused a dramatic issue in the performance of the dashboard.
**Every page now spends more than 5' to give me results, before the pages were loaded in less than 10''.**

I tried to use:

- **The parameter @id1 directly in the FROM SQL** but it is not automatically substituted and it causes an error `Not found: Table my_project.table_@{id1} was not found in location EU`
- an **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** but it is not recognized by the tool

When I try to use direct one of the 1k table suffixes, for example id 400:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `my_project.table_400` AS a
WHERE a.date BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) AND PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
      AND a.user_email =    @DS_USER_EMAIL
```

the performances are exactly the same as before, but, I must filter for reporting.

[I know that the wildcard tables are limited in many aspects( cache for example)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations) but, testing the query on BigQuery, the time spent is 0/1 second.

Is there something that I miss/I can change on the query?
Do you have some advice/suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: how about partitioning by id and clustering by date and email?

Comment: Hi @AlexYes,
I've split the `my_project.big_table` into many tables to avoid partitioning by id.

Are you suggesting a partitioning by id and clustering by 
date and email on the 1k table suffixes?

Comment: no without suffixes - in a single table

Comment: hi @AlexYes, having a unique table is what I want to avoid because my table in the reporting is used by 800+ customers so the costs go up dramatically.

Comment: when you partition the table BQ trims the cost when query has a filter on a partitioned column, doesn't it?

Comment: I think I've solved using https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions

Answer (score 0):

As OP mentioned, this was solved using [Table Function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions).

**Table Function** behaves just like a **VIEW** but can be used dynamically because it can accept parameters.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.